# understanding Javascript objects syntax

Tags: javascript, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <p>Creating a JavaScript Object.</p>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            var person = {
                firstName : "John",
                "lastName"  : "Doe",
                age       : 50,
                "eyeColor"  : "blue"
            };

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + " is " + person.age + " years old.";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

result is ---> John Doe is 50  years old.
here whether the property firstName,"lastName" is enclosed in quotes or not the code still works.but what is the technical difference and in which cases it won't work
for example in JSON the person object's  firstName property is invalid json syntax unless the quotes are present.
but javascript allows either syntax to work

Comment: In JSON the the quotes are required. In js object literals, they're not. Don't quote property names in js unless you have a reason.

Comment: JSON is a subset of js and is much stricter. This just means in JSON is stricter and requires property names to be quotes. Inline js notation is looser and does not require the quotes. This being said, any json should be generated using serializer.

Comment: serializing methods using stringify is not possible though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript object may have key names enclosed in quotes or without quotes. This feature has more significance when the key name contains a special character like -, white space etc.

Foe example

```
var person = {
   first Name : "John", // Will not work
  "last Name"  : "Doe", // Will work
  age       : 50,
  "eyeColor"  : "blue"
};
```